# Calling javascript from controller Ruby on Rails 3.2.9

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I hope you will help me with a little problem.

I have some code in ror controller:

```
  def create
    @email = Email.new(params[:email])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @email.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.json { render json: @email, status: :created, location: @email }

      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @email.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And if email saved,

```
if @email.save
```

I want div to be showed in HTML file

```
<div id="notice">OK</div>
```

with this javascript

```
document.getElementById("notice").style.display = 'block';
```

But I don't know where should I put js file and how I should call it from controller.

Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript is executed in the client's browser, therefore you should but this into the HTML template.

Comment: I think I should give a "sign" from controller to template that it's time to use js power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails will be looking for the 'new' template to return to the user when the render action is called. The specified action is used to determine which view to render.

You will want to place the JavaScript in this template.  Once the user posts to your controller the 'new' template will be returned to their browser and your JavaScript can be executed client side.

For more information please see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html